# CAST Method for finding value of $\theta$.

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

Hi, So I'm having little trouble with the above question.  So what I've done here is firstly found the $\sin^{-1}$ and $\cos^{-1}$ for these two.

They sin = 30 degrees and cos = 150 degrees respectively.

So I then have drawn up using the CAST Method:

[image]

So:  Since there is both a positive sine, and a negative cos, the quadrant would be under the 'sine is positive' quadrant.

So that means that I would use $ x = 180 - α $
So therefore, it is $ x = 180 - 30 $ = 150 degrees.

However, my question is: *Why do I do $180 - 30$?  How do I know that it is the SINE angle I have to minus, why not the cosine angle in this particular scenario?  How do I know how to minus which is which?*

Hope this makes sense!

Comment: You just use CAST. You have $\sin(180^o-x)=\sin x=-\sin(180^o+x)=-\sin(-x)$ and $\cos(180^o-x)=\cos(180^o+x)=-\cos x=-\cos(-x)$. There are various ways of proving that, depending on how you define $\cos x,\sin x$.

Answer (score 2):

> Given that $\sin\theta = \dfrac{1}{2}$ and that $\cos\theta = -\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $0^\circ \leq \theta \leq 360^\circ$, find the value of $\theta$.

Since $\sin\theta > 0$ and $\cos\theta < 0$, you have correctly concluded that $\theta$ is a second-quadrant angle.  You also took the inverse cosine of $-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, from which you can conclude that $\theta = 150^\circ$.

Let's see why.

I will be working in [radians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian).

The arccosine function (inverse cosine function) $\arccos: [-1, 1] \to [0, \pi]$ is defined by $\arccos x = \theta$ if $\theta$ is the unique angle in $[0, \pi]$ such that $\cos\theta = x$.

[image: arccosine_graph]

Since $\dfrac{5\pi}{6}$ is the unique angle $\theta \in [0, \pi]$ such that $\cos\theta = -\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, 
$$\theta = \arccos\left(-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right) = \dfrac{5\pi}{6}$$
Converting to degrees yields $\theta = 150^\circ$.

To reiterate, since there is only one angle $\theta$ in $[0, \pi]$ such that $\cos\theta = -\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, we may conclude that 
$$\theta = \arccos\left(-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right) = \frac{5\pi}{6}$$

While it is not needed to solve this problem, consider the diagram below.

[image: symmetry_diagram_for_sine_and_cosine_functions]

Two angles in standard position (vertex at the origin, initial side on the positive $x$-axis) have the same sine if the $y$-coordinates of the points where their terminal sides intersect the unit circle are equal.  By symmetry, 
$$\sin(\pi - \theta) = \sin\theta$$ 
Any angle coterminal with one of these angles will also have the same sine.  Hence, $\sin\theta = \sin\varphi$ if 
$$\varphi = \theta + 2n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}$$
or 
$$\varphi = \pi - \theta + 2n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}$$
Two angles in standard position have the same cosine if the $x$-coordinates of the points where their terminal sides intersect the unit circle are equal.  By symmetry, 
$$\cos(-\theta) = \cos\theta$$
Any angle coterminal with one of these angles will also have the same cosine.  Hence, $\cos\theta = \cos\varphi$ if 
$$\varphi = \theta + 2n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}$$
or 
$$\varphi = -\theta + 2n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Answer (score 1):

You have identified the correct quadrant. We know that $\sin(30^{\circ})= \frac{1}{2}$. However we are not interested in the angle in the first quadrant, we want the angle in the second quadrant. By symmetry this is just $(180-30)^{\circ}$.[image]

In the figure above, we see in the first quadrant we have identified theta. But we need to identify what this value is the second quadrant. So starting from the $x$-axis we go $180^{\circ}$ anticlockwise to arrive at the second quadrant and then go back through $\theta^{\circ}$ clockwise.