# Solving $ 4\sin(3\theta + 2) = 1 $

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

> Find all $ \theta \in (0, 2\pi)$ satisfying
> $$ 4\sin(3\theta + 2) = 1 $$

I tried using a the right triangle and I tried opening up the $\sin$ function too. But nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\sin(3\theta+2)=\frac{1}{4}$ and taking the $arcsin$ of both sides and using the CAST method ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1828209/cast-method-for-finding-value-of-theta) for examples) or sketching the graph, gives the set of all solutions to be:

- $3\theta+2=2n\pi+sin^{-1}(\frac{1}{4})$
- $3\theta+2=2n\pi+\pi-sin^{-1}(\frac{1}{4})$

for $n\in\mathbb Z$.

Now you have to find all $\theta$'s in $(0,2\pi$) (you should have [6](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4sin%283x%2B2%29%3D1%20for%20x%20between%200%20and%202pi) solutions).

Comment: Type `$\sin x$`, `$\cos x$`, `$\tan x$`, `$\csc x$`, `$\sec x$`, `$\cot x$`, `$\arcsin x$`, `$\arccos x$`, and `$\arctan x$` to obtain $\sin x$, $\cos x$, $\tan x$, $\csc x$, $\sec x$, $\cot x$, $\arcsin x$, $\arccos x$, and $\arctan x$, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Dividing both sides by $4$, we have

$$
\sin(3\theta+2)=\frac{1}{4}
$$

Then, let $y=3\theta+2$:

$$
\sin y=\frac{1}{4}
$$

And use a calculator to find $\arcsin \frac{1}{4}$. This gives you the *principal* solution to the equation. However, we need to solve for $\theta$, not $y$, and we also need to pay attention to the range of values that $\theta$ can take:

\begin{align}
0&\leq\theta\leq2\pi \\
\implies0&\leq3\theta\leq6\pi \\
\implies2&\leq y\leq6\pi+2
\end{align}

Once you have found all the possible values of $y$, use these to find the values of $\theta$. As Wrench has pointed out, a good way to find all the possible values of $y$ is by using a CAST diagram, or by considering the symmetries of the sine graph.