# Solve $25\cos(\theta - 73.74) = 15$ for $ 0\leq \theta \leq 360$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Solve $25\cos(\theta - 73.74) = 15$ for $0 \leq \theta \leq 360$

There are gaps in my understanding, specifically at the very end of this process. I simplify the above to:
$$ \cos(\theta - 73.74) = \frac{3}{5}$$

$$ \theta = 53.15 $$

If anyone could detail the *exact* process out, with explanations as to why we do what we do next, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: $$ \theta-73.74= 53.15$$, So $$\theta=126.89$$

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [CAST method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1828209/cast-method-for-finding-value-of-theta) or just [sketch](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wjxuyo8x1z) the cosine function to see that there are infinitely many solutions. Then find which ones lie in the interval $0^{\circ}\leq \theta \leq 360^{\circ}.$

We have $$ \cos(\theta - 73.74^{\circ}) = \frac{3}{5}$$
$$ \theta - 73.74^{\circ}= 53.1301^{\circ}+360^{\circ}n $$
$$\theta - 73.74^{\circ}= -53.1301^{\circ}+360^{\circ}k $$
That is
$$ \theta = 126.87^{\circ}+360^{\circ}n $$
$$\theta= 20.61^{\circ}+360^{\circ}k $$

for $n,k\in\mathbb Z$. So choosing $n=0$ for the first and $k=0$ for the second we obtain the two solutions in the required interval to be: $$\theta = 126.87^{\circ} \space \space \text{and}\space \space \theta = 20.61^{\circ}.$$

Comment: I discovered what is called "CAST method", funny but it does not deserve the honor to be called a "method", and moreover, pardon me, I don't see the point to invoke it in this context.

Comment: It is also called CAST rule, CAST diagram or unit circle method.

Comment: Is this method the same for sine and tangent equations?

Comment: Yes, see [this](https://www.onlinemathlearning.com/trig-equations-cast.html) for more examples.

Answer (score 2):

I always draw a graph for these questions. The usual method is to substitute $u = x-73.74$, solve for $u$, and then find the values of $x$ which correspond to the solutions in $u$.

$$$$

A similar method:

First, take a look at the graph, and try to see if you can understand how it addresses your question directly.

I've written on the graph $74^\circ$ instead of $73.74^\circ$ because it would take up too much room on the diagram.

$ \cos(\theta - 73.74) = \frac{3}{5}.$

"Principal value": $\theta_1 - 73.74 = \arccos(\frac{3}{5}) = 53.13...^\circ $
$\implies \theta_1 = 53.13 + 73.74 = 126.87...^\circ,$ and since $0 \leq 126.87...^\circ \leq 360^\circ$, this is the first solution. It is the right red circle on my diagram. Also, from the graph, by symmetry around $73.74^\circ$, the left red circle has value $\theta_2 = 73.74 - (126.87...-73.74) = 20.609...^\circ$ So the solutions are: $\theta_1 = 127^\circ$ and $\theta_2 = 20.6^\circ (3sf)$.

[image]

Comment: [+1] for the graphical explanation, although I think that in most cases, like this one, a mechanical application of equivalence rules can as well serve as a blind stick.

Answer (score 0):

The cosine value is positive, the corresponding angle is in the first or the fourth quadrant.

$$0 \le \theta \le 360^\circ$$
$$-73.74^\circ \le \theta-73.74^\circ \le (360-73.74)^\circ$$

Hence we have

- $$\theta-73.74^\circ = \pm 53.13^\circ$$

Comment: Small discrepancy : 53.13 instead of 53.54.

Comment: Thanks for the correction

Answer (score 0):

[The angle unit is the (decimal) degree]

Write your equation under the form

$$\cos(\theta-73.74)=\cos(53.13)$$

Let us proceed by equivalence.

One must not miss the fact that 2 cosines are equal iff the corresponding angles are equal or opposite (mod 360):

$$\cos(u)=\cos(v) \iff u=v+k 360 \ \text{or} \  u=-v+k 360$$

($k \in \mathbb{Z}$) giving :

$$\theta-73.74=53.13+k 360 \ \text{or} \  \theta-73.74=-53.13+k 360$$

otherwise said:

$$\theta-73.74=53.13+k 360 \ \text{or} \  \theta-73.74=-53.13+k 360$$

$$\theta=126.87+k 360  \ \text{or} \  \theta = 20.61+k 360.$$

As the answers are desired in $[0,360)$, we can drop the $k 360$, giving the

$$\text{Final answer:} \ \theta=126.87  \ \text{or} \  \theta = 20.61.$$

Comment: Is this method the same for sine and tangent equations?

Comment: For sine, it is changed into : $\sin(u)=\sin(v) \ \iff \ u=v+k 360 \ \text{or} \  u=(180-v)+k 360$; For tangent: $\tan(u)=\tan(v) \iff u=v+k 180.$

Answer (score 0):

A polar plot is perhaps more instructive than a graph.

Draw a circle through origin diameter $5$ cutting x-axis at $r=x=3.,\theta=0. $

Pythagorean triplet sides $(3,4,5)$ are seen in the right triangle when you take a good look.

The circle has equation in *polar coordinate form*

$$ r= a \cos (\theta- \alpha) ;\; r=3, a=5;\; \alpha= 53.13^{\circ};\;$$

or

$$ @\theta=0, r=3,   @\theta=\alpha, r=5,  @\theta=90^{\circ}, r=4 \quad $$

$$ 5 \cos \alpha= 3,\; 5 \sin \alpha=4,\; 5^2=3^2+4^2. \; $$

[image]